# Insert forms from a query in postgis

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I try to insert a polygon in my table `geofield` from a query. The table `geofield` is defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE geofield(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, field GEOMETRY);

insert into geofield(field) values (myfield)
SELECT
    'POLYGON(('||cast((select lat from coordinates where id=1)as varchar)||' '||
      cast((select lon from coordinates where id=1)as varchar)||','||
      cast((select lat from coordinates where id=2)as varchar)||' '||
      cast((select lon from coordinates where id=2)as varchar)||','||
      cast((select lat from coordinates where id=3)as varchar)||' '||
      cast((select lon from coordinates where id=3)as varchar)||','||
      cast((select lat from coordinates where id=4)as varchar)||' '||
      cast((select lon from coordinates where id=4)as varchar)||','||
      cast((select lat from coordinates where id=1)as varchar)||' '||
      cast((select lon from coordinates where id=1)as varchar)||'))') AS myfield;
```

The SELECT alone returns me:

```
POLYGON((46.744628268759314 6.569952920654968,46.74441692818192 6.570487107359068,46.74426116111054 6.570355867853787,46.74447250168793 6.569821681149689,46.744628268759314 6.569952920654968))
```

But it doesn't work, I tryed too with ST_GeomFromText but same result.

Comment: The appropriate syntax of `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` does not include the `VALUES` part. So: `INSERT INTO geofield (field) SELECT whatever`.

Comment: Also, specifying the actual error or behaviour you're getting is definitely a requirement. "It doesn't work" is just useless.

Comment: Thank you so much! it was the VALUES who locked me, I spend so many time to try figure it out :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid working with text concatenation and work with plain [PostGIS functions](http://postgis.net/docs/reference.html) instead:

```
SELECT
    /* Make a polygon from the linestring */
    ST_MakePolygon(
        /* Close the polygon */
        ST_AddPoint(
            t.linestring,
            ST_StartPoint(t.linestring)
        )
    )
FROM (
    SELECT
        /* Aggregate into a linestring */
        ST_MakeLine(ST_MakePoint(c.lon, c.lat) ORDER BY c.id) AS linestring
    FROM coordinates AS c
) t
;
```

Following your [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39137896/querying-json-in-postgres/39144359), you could get it back from the `json` directly if you wish:

```
SELECT
    /* Make a polygon from the linestring */
    ST_MakePolygon(
        /* Close the polygon */
        ST_AddPoint(
            t.linestring,
            ST_StartPoint(t.linestring)
        )
    )
FROM (
    SELECT
        /* Aggregate into a linestring */
        ST_MakeLine(ST_MakePoint(c.lon, c.lat) ORDER BY c.id) AS linestring
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            e.id,
            (e.element->>'lat')::numeric AS lat,
            (e.element->>'lon')::numeric AS lon
        FROM
            field AS f,
            json_array_elements(f.data->'vertices') WITH ORDINALITY AS e(element, id)
    ) AS c
) t
;
```

Comment: Thank you! Finally, I use your last solution. It's the more efficient one :) now I deal with another json file with points to place in the polygon and thanks to your help I think I can manage it my self.

Comment: @gabrielchauviere: You're welcome. And, well, you could mark the answers as accepted then (in both questions)... ;)

Answer (score 2):

The string is in proper WKT format, so that is not the problem. What is a problem is that you have longitude and latitude values reversed and the syntax of the `INSERT` is wrong. You should also convert the string to a `geometry` first:

```
INSERT INTO geofield(field)
    SELECT ST_GeomFromText(
        'POLYGON(('||cast((select lat from coordinates where id=1)as varchar)||' '||
          cast((select lon from coordinates where id=1)as varchar)||','||
          cast((select lat from coordinates where id=2)as varchar)||' '||
          cast((select lon from coordinates where id=2)as varchar)||','||
          cast((select lat from coordinates where id=3)as varchar)||' '||
          cast((select lon from coordinates where id=3)as varchar)||','||
          cast((select lat from coordinates where id=4)as varchar)||' '||
          cast((select lon from coordinates where id=4)as varchar)||','||
          cast((select lat from coordinates where id=1)as varchar)||' '||
          cast((select lon from coordinates where id=1)as varchar)||'))');
```

But this is all very wasteful and not suitable for larger polygons. As long as your polygons are composed of a single ring, you can do this, which will be much faster and less prone to error:

```
INSERT INTO geofield(field)
    SELECT ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((' || coords.c || ',' || coord1.c || '))', 4326)
    FROM
        ( SELECT string_agg(lon::text || ' ' || lat::text, ',' ORDER BY id) AS c
          FROM coordinates ) coords,
        ( SELECT lon::text || ' ' || lat::text AS c
          FROM coordinates
          WHERE id = 1 ) coord1;
```

The first sub-query strings all the coordinates together, while the second only get the first coordinate to close the polygon. Works with as many points as you might have.

Comment: Thank you, I'll never think about that (I'm not an SQL expert), it works very well!

Comment: the only mistake is the ORDER BY who returns an error : column "coordinates.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function. I removed it and it works

Comment: First, the way you use `ORDER BY` there does not guarantee order either, you should have `ORDER BY` *inside* `string_agg` function call instead of having it on the query (it is useless on the query actually). Second, you are aggregating and getting "id" unaggregated, but you are not using `GROUP BY` (the fix of the first should fix this too, just move `ORDER BY` from the query to the aggregate funciton call, as I did in my answer)

Comment: @MatheusOl Absolutely right and thanks for pointing that out. Answer updated.